# Using JQuery to bind "focus" and "blur" functions for "window", doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use JQuery like the follwoing:

```
var focusFlag = 1;
jQuery(window).bind("focus", function(event)
{
focusFlag = 1;
});

jQuery(window).bind("blur", function(event)
{
focusFlag = 0;
});
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work for IE?

Comment: At the risk of sounding idiotic, you have put that within a $(document).ready block?

Comment: No, I didn't put them within a $(document).ready block. But I found another way that doesn't using JQuery way: http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/detect-browser-window-focus

Comment: @Mickey Shine - try putting them within a $(document).ready block.

Comment: @karim79 if you have tested it and it works, why not adding as an answer?

Answer (score 109):

Just to have the right answer here:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).focus(function() {
        console.log('Focus');
    });

    $(window).blur(function() {
        console.log('Blur');
    });
});
```

Note that in FF and IE the "Focus" event fires on ~document load, while in Chrome it only fires if the window had lost focus before and now it has regained it.

Comment: Still good to have the answer. This was the first link I found on the topic.

Comment: It Worked...Thank you

Comment: Haha Phil you have much to learn... or... at least you *did*, ~7 years ago. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I'm only repeating what Shedal and roosteronacid have said, you need the DOM to be ready before you can bind events to it otherwise in some browsers computer will say no and it will die silently.

To do this you use the jQuery .ready() function explained by roosteronacid:

```
var focusFlag = 1;

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(window).bind("focus",function(event){
        focusFlag = 1;
    }).bind("blur", function(event){
        focusFlag = 0;
    });
});
```

What it does is the .ready() function will only fire and run the code inside it when the DOM has completely loaded from the server.

The only real changes I have made is that I **hug** my brackets for easy reading but it's a personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(window)
```

does not work in all browsers.

Try

```
$('body')
```