# Firefox 5 inactive tab jQuery animation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have coded a slider to my project but it fails on chrome and firefox5.
Slider has a info bar and if page is in inactive tab, it queues the animation of infobar and when i return to the my page it repeats animation n times.

How can i fix that issue ? :(

I try: setTimeout but it couses a new bug that infobar never seems :S

The test link of my project is here : http://demo.cihanuygun.com/polo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active) about how to detect the window losing and gaining focus and in your slidebox() function, don't queue up an animation if the window does not have focus.

Comment: thank you according to your tip i have solved this issue with this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408699/using-jquery-to-bind-focus-and-blur-functions-for-window-doesnt-work-in-i