# jQuery focus when leaving a window in IE8

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to give the user a modal window when the leave the browser, and clicked on the taskbar or something.

The following code works in FF, Chrome, IE9, etc.  But it does NOT work in IE8. What am I missing here?

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).focus(function () {
                $("#dialog-message").dialog("close");
            })
                    .blur(function () {                           
                        var options = {};
                        $("#dialog-message").dialog({
                                modal: true,
                            position: 'center',
                            resizable: false,
                            closeOnEscape: true,
                            open: function (event, ui) {
                                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog).hide();
                            },
                            show: "explode",
                            hide: "explode"
                        });
                    }).trigger('focus');


                });
```

Comment: Have you tried with `$("body")`? It might be the same effect but who knows.

Comment: Haven't tried this before, and can't test IE8 myself, but try it on the `body` tag as @VisioN suggested, and give it a `tabindex` attribute. Sometimes IE needs that to handle focus/blur on non-form elements.

Comment: @ jmar777: sounds like something :)

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408699/ some suggest to place the event bindings inside `$(function() { ... })` (i.e. document ready) block. Possibly it helps.

Comment: Tried $('body') that made it behave even worse.

Comment: Hmm... for IE, try `$(document).on('focusin', ...)` and `$(document).on('focusout', ...)`.

Comment: @jmar777 You think bubbling makes sense?

Comment: Not sure - just thrown some ideas out there lol. Seems like event delegation could work - maybe just look for any `blur` event that bubbles to the document, and then show a dialog if no `focus` events occur within ~50ms or so?

Comment: Here's a POC - can someone try it in IE8? http://jsfiddle.net/y2aXt/

Comment: Hold on - fixed a bug causing blur condition to fire twice: http://jsfiddle.net/y2aXt/1/

Answer (score 1):

It could be something simple like having white space before the .blur