# Is there an event in javascript for app switch on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios

On iOS, while I am in the browser, I can switch to another app, do something and after come back to the browser.

I know that web page isn't reloaded in this case. However, I wonder whether any events exist which I can handle to do some actions (as example show an alert) when user comes back to browser.

So, it should look like this

- A user opens a page and an alert is shown
- A user goes to another iOS app
- A user comes back to the browser (which is on my page)
- The alert is shown again.

Comment: Have you tried [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6521899/382982)

Comment: @ethagnawl: Interesting idea. I will.