# stop animation on window blur

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, it fades elements in and out in a repeating cycle. When the tab is inactive the text within the divs piles up on top of each other for a split second before being cleared when the tab is activated again. Is there a way to stop this animation when the window blurs and start it again on focus?

```
(cycle = function () {

    setTimeout(function(){$('#right').fadeOut(1000)},10000);
    setTimeout(function(){$('right').fadeIn(1000)}, 11000);
    setTimeout(function(){$('#left').fadeOut(1000)},13000);
    setTimeout(function(){$('#left').fadeIn(1000)},14000);
    setTimeout(function(){$('#left').fadeOut(1000)},15000);
    setTimeout(function(){$('#left').fadeIn(1000)},17000);

})();
```

Comment: You might try looking [at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408699/using-jquery-to-bind-focus-and-blur-functions-for-window-doesnt-work-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave a suggestion in a comment, but then remembered that that solution is not necessarily cross-browser compatible, as I had come across it before, thus the creation of my plugin.

Suffice it to say, `$(window).blur()` and `focus` do not always work as expected on all browsers. I don't remember the exact list of problems I ran into, but I know some were things like; clicking on another tab (in FF, i think) did not trigger the blur, clicking on another program would trigger the blur despite the fact my main browser window was still open and that tab had focus, it ddnt have Windows Focus, etc...

The following plugin I created might be helpful in that I've filed it down to work in "most" browsers and versions (not tested on all versions) and it functions exactly as we expect where I work. It only goes blur if the exact browser window's tab loses focus to another tab of the same browser. And of course vice versa with focus.

### See jsFiddle Example usage and unminified code

### Minified Plugin:

<sub>Simply Add to a js file to be called after jquery or place at top of your code</sub>

```
(function(jQuery){jQuery.winFocus||(jQuery.extend({winFocus:function(b){function c(a){a=a||window.event;a.hidden=a.type in{focus:"visible",focusin:"visible",pageshow:"visible",blur:"hidden",focusout:"hidden",pagehide:"hidden"}?"focusout"===a.type:this[d];jQuery(window).data("visible",!a.hidden);jQuery.winFocus.methods.exeCB(a)}var d="hidden";d in document?document.addEventListener("visibilitychange",c):(d="mozHidden")in document?document.addEventListener("mozvisibilitychange",c):(d="webkitHidden")in document?
document.addEventListener("webkitvisibilitychange",c):(d="msHidden")in document?document.addEventListener("msvisibilitychange",c):"onfocusin"in document?document.onfocusin=document.onfocusout=c:window.onpageshow=window.onpagehide=window.onfocus=window.onblur=c;for(x in arguments)"object"==typeof arguments[x]?(arguments[x].blur&&(jQuery.winFocus.methods.blur=arguments[x].blur),arguments[x].focus&&(jQuery.winFocus.methods.focus=arguments[x].focus),arguments[x].blurFocus&&(jQuery.winFocus.methods.blurFocus=
arguments[x].focus)):"function"==typeof arguments[x]&&(void 0===jQuery.winFocus.methods.blurFocus?jQuery.winFocus.methods.blurFocus=arguments[x]:(jQuery.winFocus.methods.blur=jQuery.winFocus.methods.blurFocus,jQuery.winFocus.methods.blurFocus=void 0,jQuery.winFocus.methods.focus=arguments[x]))}}),jQuery.winFocus.methods={blurFocus:void 0,blur:void 0,focus:void 0,exeCB:function(b){jQuery.winFocus.methods.blurFocus?jQuery.winFocus.methods.blurFocus(b,!b.hidden):b.hidden?jQuery.winFocus.methods.blur&&
jQuery.winFocus.methods.blur(b):jQuery.winFocus.methods.focus&&jQuery.winFocus.methods.focus(b)}})})(jQuery);
```

<sub>Also: #line-o 's referenced SO Question is where I was first inspired to write this plugin and I also have this plugin answer posted there. lol</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Visibility API](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/) for current browser. You'll still need a fallback for older ones (namely IEs).

Or you might find a solution here: 
[Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active/)