# Remove event listener from window object using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I am trying to remove `blur` and `focus` event listeners from window object using jquery's unbind function using:

```
function removeWindowEvents(){
    $(window).unbind('blur') ; 
    $(window).unbind('focus') ;
}
```

I registered the event using Javascript:

```
function addEvents(){
window.addEventListener('blur', function(){ document.title = "Blurred" ; });
window.addEventListener('focus', function(){ document.title = "In Focus" ;}); 


}
```

This however does not work. What am I doing wrong? I tested this is Mozilaa and Chrome(latest versions)

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: You should show how you registered the event listeners.

Comment: Adding that bit of code. I tested across Firefox and chrome.

Comment: Have you tried using `off` as well?

Comment: Tried off as well. Does not work.

Comment: @EricHotinger `.unbind()` internally just calls `.off()` so this does not make a difference. Most likely the event listeners where not attached using jQuery (or with another version if multiple where loaded).

Comment: If you bind your events with .on() then you can unbind them with .off() Use jQuery for both instead of native to bind and then jQuery to unbind

Comment: Works when I use .on() instead of JS.

Comment: @frenchie , you can answer. I will accept. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EricHotinger for current jQuery only `.on` and `.off` _exists_. The other _old_  ways are just a  mapping to the `.on` and `.off`. Thats why they are preferred over the old functions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't do it your way.

jQuery can only unbind all event handlers for a given event if the original listeners were configured using jQuery.

This is because an event that is added with `addEventListener()` must be removed with `removeEventListener()` and `removeEventListener()` requires a second argument that specifies the callback function.

From the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener):

```
target.removeEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture])
```

If the event is originally registered using jQuery, jQuery works around this by having only one master event registered with addEventListener that points to it's own callback function and then using it's own event dispatching to all the events registered via jQuery.  This allows it to support generic `.unbind()` like you're trying to use, but it will only work if the original event is registered with jQuery and thus goes through the jQuery event handler management system.

So, without jQuery, you would do it like this:

```
function blurHandler() {
    document.title = "Blurred" ;
}

function focusHandler() {
    document.title = "In Focus" ;
}

function addEvents(){
    window.addEventListener('blur', blurHandler);
    window.addEventListener('focus', focusHandler); 
}

function removeWinowEvents() {
    window.removeEventListener('blur', blurHandler);
    window.removeEventListener('focus', focusHandler);
}
```

With jQuery, you could do it like this:

```
function addEvents(){
    $(window).on('blur', function(){ document.title = "Blurred" ; })
             .on('focus', function(){ document.title = "In Focus" ;}); 
}

function removeWindowEvents() {
    $(window).off('blur focus');
}
```

Comment: The callback function must be the same as the one you added in the event listener adding. ie. If you add an event listener myCallBack then while removing event listener myCallBack should be the function removed

Answer (score 0):

try binding with jquery
see [Using JQuery to bind "focus" and "blur" functions for "window", doesn't work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408699/using-jquery-to-bind-focus-and-blur-functions-for-window-doesnt-work-in)

```
$(function() {
    $(window).focus(function() {
        console.log('Focus');
    });

    $(window).blur(function() {
        console.log('Blur');
    });
});
```