# Why does my script break when browser tab not in focus

Tags: javascript, browser

When the page loads, the script for the background stripes runs fine.. the stripes appear then begin to fade out after a certain amount of stripes is in the array.

As long as the browser tab is selected(focus) the script runs as expected. However, If you open a New browser tab and select the new tab. The script for the stripes continues to run in the background on the original tab but somehow ignores the condition and the stripes pile up to infinity. When switching back to the original tab you then see the ugly pile up.

Why is this happening?

https://codepen.io/trentHarlem/full/yLVvvav

```
const addButton = document.getElementById('add-stripe');
const guitar = document.getElementById('guitar');

function addStripe() {
  let qsaSpan = document.querySelectorAll('span');
  let stripe = document.createElement('span');
  let stripeArray = Array.from(qsaSpan);

    let color = 'white';
    let z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    if (Math.random() > 0.65) {
      color = 'black';
    }
    let angle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) - 15;
    let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) - 15;
    let width = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    // console.log('click', color, angle, x, y, width);

    stripe.style.backgroundColor = `${color}`;
    stripe.style.zIndex = `${z}`;
    stripe.style.transform += `translateX(${x}%)`;
    stripe.style.transform += `translateY(${y}%)`;
    stripe.style.transform += `rotate(${angle}deg)`;
    stripe.style.height = `${width}%`;
    guitar.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', stripe);
  // console.log('length', stripeArray.length);
  

  function parRemove() {
    stripeArray[0].remove()
    stripeArray[0].removeEventListener('transitionend', parRemove)
    stripeArray[0].removeEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', parRemove)
  }

  if (stripeArray.length > 5) {
    stripeArray[0].classList.add('fall');
    stripeArray[0].classList.add('fade');
//    console.log(' stripeArray[0].classList', stripeArray[0].classList.value);

    stripeArray[0].addEventListener('transitionend', parRemove, false);
    stripeArray[0].addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', parRemove, false);
  }
    else if (stripeArray.length < 5) {
  
  }
}
const stripeTimer = setInterval(addStripe, 2000);
```

Comment: It's working for me.

Comment: [browsers throttle timers in background tabs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs)

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks for the heads up.  So to avoid this, would you recommend I rewrite the script to use requestAnimationFrame()?

Comment: That will have the same limitations I guess. Just make your script resistent to running less often than every two seconds. Not quite sure how though, I don't quite get how it works.

Comment: What's the reason to attach `stripeArray[0].addEventListener('transitionend', parRemove, false);` only to the first element in the array? and also only after 5 other elements were inserted? I assume the problem is that transitionend triggers long before the handler is attached (when the timer is throttled)

Comment: When the 6th element appears the 0 element fades out so there should only ever be 6 on the screen with one fading in and one fading out

Comment: im looking into this RN https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008631/javascript-how-check-if-browser-got-focus