# JQuery Focus/Blur and non Jquery Focus/blur doesn't work on IE 11 (Internet explorer 11)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, focus

I want to detect if my browser window has a focus on it (is selected). I use the following code to do so:

```
$(window).focus(function() { 
    window.focusFlag = true; 
}).blur(function() { 
    window.focusFlag = false; 
});
```

Source:
[Using JQuery to bind "focus" and "blur" functions for "window", doesn't work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408699/using-jquery-to-bind-focus-and-blur-functions-for-window-doesnt-work-in)

It works on mozilla firefox 43.0.4, but it doesn't work on IE 11.

I also tried focus/blur method which does not involve JQuery.

```
function onBlur() {
    document.body.className = 'blurred';
};
function onFocus(){
    document.body.className = 'focused';
};

if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { // check for Internet Explorer
    document.onfocusin = onFocus;
    document.onfocusout = onBlur;
} else {
    window.onfocus = onFocus;
    window.onblur = onBlur;
}
```

It also works on mozilla firefox 43.0.4, but it doesn't work on IE 11.

Srource:
http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/detect-browser-window-focus

What can I do about IE 11?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Comment: @epascarello the reason I'm using these outdated methods is that I need to support older browser versions as well. That api is not supported by older browsers :(

Comment: So you use that for browsers that support it.... https://github.com/ai/visibilityjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard defines for `focus`:

> This event type is similar to focusin, but is dispatched after focus is shifted, and does not bubble.
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#events-focusevent

Therefore, [`focusin`](https://api.jquery.com/focusin/) will work for parents in jQuery.

`<input type="text" />`

`$(window).focusin(function() {
      alert("Focussed");
     }).focusout(function() {
      alert("Blur");
});`

[Try in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harishkommuri/8kowhhhm/)